# How to use pie chart to visualize firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, charts, data-visualization

I couldnt find any tutorials related to pie charts for data visualization. can someone help with it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in Gradle-app

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView( R.id.pieChart ) PieChart pieChart;
private ArrayList<Entry> nutrientsArray = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> nutrientsNameArray = new ArrayList<>();
private PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(nutrientsArray, "Macro-Nutrients in grams");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_detail );
    ButterKnife.bind( this );


    nutrientsArray.add(new Entry("120g", 0));
    nutrientsArray.add(new Entry("330g", 1));
    nutrientsArray.add(new Entry("80g", 2));

    nutrientsNameArray.add(getString( R.string.protein ));
    nutrientsNameArray.add(getString( R.string.carbs ));
    nutrientsNameArray.add(getString( R.string.fats ));

    PieData pieData = new PieData(nutrientsNameArray, dataSet);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
    dataSet.setColors( ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
    dataSet.setValueTextColor( Color.WHITE);
    dataSet.setValueTextSize(20);
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(5f);
    pieChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
    Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setEnabled(true);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called MPChart. Here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) repo

Here is the article on it's implementation [Implementing the Chart using MP Chart](https://javapapers.com/android/android-chart-example-app-using-mpandroidchart/)

Hope this helps!